# Excel function with vlookup, left and substitute

Tags: excel, vba

So I need a function that allows me to convert a 00:90:7f:b3:ff:02 to 00907fb3ff02
then from there to the first six characters to = 00907f. After that I need it to do a vlookup to a second worksheet and match  for example

Samsung      00907f

I know how to do these things all separately with left, substitute and vlookup. Is there a way to make this into one vba function? is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most effective help on the site. If you have a vba tag and no code sample that you have tried, your question will most likely be closed. Also, its possible vba may not be necessary. If you can provide more examples of the data on your second sheet, that may help as well.

Comment: To answer your two questions: yes and yes. That leaves a question in response: why over-complicate what is a non-array standard formula of medium complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this part of formula in your vlookup:

> LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",""),6)

Replace A1 with the cell reference of the MAC Address

What this will do is show the first **Left** 6 characters of the Mac address but before we show it, it will use **substitute** to remove any: **:**

Hope this helps.